# Sounddevice failing at import with Python 3.7.7 (x64) on Windows 10

Tags: pip, python-sounddevice

I get this error message when I try to run the following script, or any script with `import sounddevice` at top.  I installed sound device at cmd as admin with `pip install sounddevice` and I verified it is there with `pip list`

```
Assertion failed!

Program: C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
File: src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c, Line 1061

Expression: FALSE
```

Example program:

```
import sounddevice

sounddevice.get_portaudio_version()
input('enter to exit')
```

Another example prog (from [1](https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/#python-sounddevice)):

```
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf

data, fs = sf.read('ImperialMarch60.wav')
sd.play(data, fs)
status = sd.wait()
```

update/Further clarification:

I've tried reinstalling sounddevice and python as well as using sounddevice 0.3.12 or python 3.8.3 instead.  I only have 1 ver of python installed at a time.   I've had Audacity for a long time and that works.

Downloaded a whl from `https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#sounddevice` and ran `pip install sounddevice-0.3.15-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` which installed but produced the same "assertion failed" error.  I didn't think this was related but I couldn't do `pip install pyaudio` bc it said `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required` even though I installed Visual Studio Build Tools 2019, so I downloaded the gohlke whl for pyaudio and suddenly sounddevice works...  so this is somewhat resolved but I don't get it.  Perhaps portaudio is not "automagically" included in sounddevice for Windows as the sounddevice documentation says[2](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.15/installation.html)?

Update2: I uninstalled the sounddevice whl and reinstalled using pypl version using `pip install sounddevice` and now it works too...

Comment: See [issue #7](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/issues/7).

Comment: I tried the methods in that thread which still seems unresolved itself and they also did not work for me. I edited my original post to include what I tried from that thread

Comment: Just to be sure, `pip install sounddevice-0.3.15-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` will not install the wheel unless the sounddevice is first uninstalled with `pip uninstall sounddevice`

Comment: I did uninstall first before trying the whl.  BTW, thank you for the repository and all your work; critical enabler for me!